# biblatex fancyhdr inconsistency

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, tufte

In the following MWE the chapter title in the header gets set `\smallcaps` which is defined as

```
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[50]{##1}}%
\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
```

but this is not applied to the bibliography header.

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{biblatex,lipsum}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
How can I achieve that the bibliography header is set the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a special bib heading for `tufte`:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibheading{tufte}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Book title}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=tufte]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to use that `\defbibheading` also for adding the bibliography in the table of contents.